# Blender 3.6.0 File Browser

Tags: file-browser

New to Blender. I'm using 3.6.0. I'm learning shortcuts. I tried <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. This brings up the File Browser.  I can't figure out how to close the File Browser.

Searching online mentioned Cancel button, Close button, Back to Previous, and complete operation and File Browser will close automatically. I even asked A.I. for help with no luck. I tried to complete an operation such as opening a file by double clicking it. Nothing happened.

How do I close the File Browser without having to exit the application? I can't find the Cancel button, Close button, or an operation to complete. I'm posting a screen shot. Hopefully the image will be larger when I post this question.

Please provide step-by-step instructions.  I'm new to Blender and still learning.

P.S. This is my first-time using Stack Exchange.

[image: Blender File Browser 3.6.0]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I've never heard of that shortcut, but: In the top left corner of the window you'll see a little folder icon. Click that and then click <kbd>3D Viewport</kbd> on the menu that appears to get back to the 3D view.

[image]

To open a Blend file you would normally use the <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Open</kbd> menu or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (or double-click on the Blend file if you don't have Blender open).

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to close it. It's opened in an [area](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/areas.html) of the main Blender's window. You can merge the are with some other area or switch it to another editor type by selecting it from the left top(or bottom as Header can be flipped to bottom) corner editor type menu:

[image]

<kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>F5</kbd> would also work to switch it back to 3D Viewport. Note that the shortcut will switch the area your mouse cursor hovers over.

See more about UI [in the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/index.html)

Comment: Also you can see each editor's shortcut in the editors popover 